# How navigate between Lightning Apps using Custom App Launcher

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, app-launcher

**Background**

I want to build a custom `App Launcher` as a lightning component using the [Lightning Design System App Launcher](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/app-launcher/#site-main-content).

I can query [AppMenuItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_AppMenuItem.htm) to get apps display:

```
SELECT Id, ApplicationId, Label, StartUrl 
FROM AppMenuItem 
WHERE IsAccessible = TRUE 
AND IsVisible = TRUE 
ORDER BY UserSortOrder NULLS LAST, SortOrder NULLS LAST LIMIT 10
```

I'd like to know how to enable the user to navigate between apps by clicking on a link?

According the [SOAP API Developer Guide: AppMenuItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_appmenuitem.htm) the `StartUrl` field is:

> For a connected app, the location users are directed to after they’ve authenticated. Otherwise, the application’s default start page.

And returns a value like:

```
https://x--x.my.salesforce.com/home/home.jsp?tsid=02u4J0000004OQ1
```

But clicking on the `StartUrl` doesn't swap the user between apps.

**Question**

1. How can I enable the user to navigate between Lightning Apps using my custom App Launcher?

Answer (score 1):

In Winter '20 there is a new feature in Lightning Navigation to navigate directly to an app. https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_lc_navigate_to_app.htm